# RehearScore crashes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

My girlfriend needs to install a software called [RehearScore](http://www.mtishows.com/resources.asp?id=6_1_0_3&theatricalresourceid=11). It's uh... Old. And it crashes when you try and run it. She has a Windows 7 on an MSI laptop. I couldn't get any error message, it just wouldn't open. I tried messing with the compatibility settings, running as an administrator, removing re-installing, etc.

She needs this software for a play she's acting in (they use it). There is literally *nothing* on the internet about this software. I would love any help in the form of:

1. a way to make it work
2. a way to debug the startup and figure what's wrong
3. a better alternative she can use
4. any other help you can offer

Comment: Do you know what the original requirements were for the software - system specs & OS? Have you tried contacting the vendor for support?

Comment: @Iszi Yes. The link I shared is their website. The system requirements are simply *"Windows XP and up"* (and when you see "Windows XP and up" you just know that this is extremely outdated). She got the installer from the people running the play, but after it didn't work I tried installing the demo from the website and that didn't work either. I don't know if contacting the website will help (I doubt it actualy, the whole thing seems like it has been dead for a few years) but I might try that. In the meantime, any other ideas?

Comment: Since she has Windows 7, try it in [XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thought about it. She has Windows 7 Premium =/

Comment: @yuvi "XP and up" implies there was already at least one newer version of Windows (i.e.: Vista) out, and they supported that OS. I'm pretty sure there's practically zero compatibility issues between Vista & 7 - at the very least, much less than between XP & 7. If none of the compatibility modes or options work, you might need to see about putting it in a VM that runs XP. Otherwise, as it's a commercial product - and a rather niche one at that - vendor support is your best bet.

Comment: @Iszi I meant that it was developed for xp which is very old OS. I understand that it *should* support Win7. Anyway, thanks for your help, I will try contacting the vendor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling the Music Theatre International main number, I got in contact with their tech Terry.  He mentions that the program needs to be installed on the local admin account, and then you need to drill down to  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\RMS    Copy the RMS folder and paste it to  C:\Users*your user account name here*\AppData\Roaming\

THEN you go to C:\Users*your user account name here*\AppData\Roaming\Coach\Shows\    And find the "Default" file.  Open it with Notepad and correct the path inside to match the path where you copied the folder.

That fixes the issue.  I hope this helps and Terry says that they are working on a patch script to assist with this error in the future.

Comment: Wow. thank you. It's been a long while since I asked this, so not really relevant anymore. But maybe it will help someone else. Give my thanks to Terry the IT Guy